# UiPath integration with Linkedin - Html characters not preserving formatting

Tags: html, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

We have an RPA on a site, to post a form. In the form we want to send HTML content with formatting. But the site is removing all the formatting, and is just showing html characters as is (like a text). But when we are copy pasting the content from tinymce editor (at our end) to the same site's form it is showing the content properly with formatting.

What needs to be done from my end while sending data to UiPath so that it puts the content in proper html format with formatting preserved?

I also tried sending html codes encoded by gson which is done by default. That also did not work.

This is when we are copy pasting the content -
[image]

And this is when we are sending data via uipath -
[image]

**EDIT**
This is what the uipath activity looks like (The description is being sent by an http api which uipath calls to get data) -
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any examples of your UiPath workflows you are using to paste the content?

Comment: Hi @Conor: Just updated the question. thanks.

Comment: Could you use a type into with sDescription rather than copying to clipboard then pasting

Comment: look at this forum: https://forum.uipath.com/t/copy-html-to-paste-html/154805/2

Answer (score 0):

Better use the **Assign** activity:

[image]

In the String variable website you simply save the HTML page. Now you can easily paste the variable anywhere. Also you don't need to paste the HTML in your editor via CTRL+V.

Just use the **Type into** activity:

[image]